# How do I represent an alphanumeric string in DCG?

Tags: parsing, prolog, bnf

I am trying to write a parser for propositional calculus encoded as S-expressions.

I have made some progress:

```
expression --> op.
op --> ['('], bin-op, bool, bool, [')'].
op --> ['('], unary-op, bool, [')'].
bool --> tok.
bool --> op.

bin-op --> ["IFF"].
bin-op --> ["IF"].
bin-op --> ["XOR"].
unary-op --> ["NOT"].

tok --> ["a"].
```

In `swipl`, I get an appropriate response from calling `phrase`:

```
?- phrase(expression, Ls).
Ls = ['(', "IFF", "a", "a", ')']
```

However this is only for the `tok` "a". Is there a way to say "tok is any alphanumeric string" in DCG? I found [this](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=dcg_basics%3Astring//1) but I'm unsure how to apply it to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to parse, then the following token will work.

```
tok([A|B], B) :- an_code(A).

alpha_numeric(X) :- 
  between(0'0, 0'9, X); between(0'A, 0'Z, X); between(0'a, 0'z, X).
an_code(A) :- atom_codes(A, C), maplist(alpha_numeric, C).
```

```
?- phrase(expression, ['(', "IFF", "A1", "1A", ')']).
true 

?- phrase(expression, ['(', "IFF", ".A1", "1A", ')']).
false.

?- phrase(expression, ['(', "IFF", ".A1", "(1A", ')']).
false.
```

With an_code as follows you can generate formulas too :

```
an_code(A) :- var(A) ->
                 length(C,L), L >= 1,
                 maplist(alpha_numeric, C),
                 string_codes(A, C);
               atom_codes(A, C), maplist(alpha_numeric, C).
```

```
?- phrase(expression, Ls).
Ls = ['(', "IFF", "0", "0", ')'] ;
Ls = ['(', "IFF", "0", "1", ')'] ;
Ls = ['(', "IFF", "0", "2", ')'] ;

?- nth0(1, Ls, "XOR"), phrase(expression, Ls).
Ls = ['(', "XOR", "0", "0", ')'] ;
Ls = ['(', "XOR", "0", "1", ')'] ;
Ls = ['(', "XOR", "0", "2", ')']

?- nth0(1, Ls, "NOT"), phrase(expression, Ls).
Ls = ['(', "NOT", "0", ')'] ;
Ls = ['(', "NOT", "1", ')'] ;
Ls = ['(', "NOT", "2", ')']
```

In generative version, some predicates used are `swi-prolog` builtin, so they man not work with other implementations.

A swi-prolog builtin `char_type/2` will also work as alpha_numeric `char_type(C, alnum)`. The following is a dcg style code using `swi-prolog` predicates.

```
tok -->
    [A],
    { string_codes(A, AC),
      maplist([C]>>char_type(C, alnum), AC)
    }.
```

Comment: You could use `between(0'0, 0'9, X) ; between(0'a, 0'z, X) ; between(0'A, 0'Z', X)` for better readability.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie : Wow, this is a very nice way of reading char as ascii. I haven't come across this before, is it implementation specific? Thank You.

Comment: No, this is standard syntax for the code values of character constants.